# My scrapy based webcrawler isnt working for the sears website

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I have written a couple of spiders that seem to working for other sites. This one has been giving me trouble.
Here is my spider code.

```
from sears.items import SwatchcolorItem

class SattySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "searsfaucet"
    allowed_domains = ["sears.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.sears.com/search=faucets?catalogId=12605&storeId=10153&levels=Home%20Improvement"
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='sears\.com/[A-Z][a-zA-Z_/]+$'),
            'parse_category', follow=True,
        ),
    )


    def parse(self, response):
        print 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        #for sel in response.xpath('//li[@class="product-wrapper grid-25 tablet-grid-33 v-spacing-large"]'):
        #for sel in response.xpath('//div[@ng-app="searchApp"]//div[@id="content"]//div[@ng-switch="resultTemplate"]'):
        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@ng-app="searchApp"]//div[@id="content"]'):
            print sel
            prod= sel.xpath('.//div[@ng-switch="resultTemplate"]')
            print prod
            produrls = sel.xpath('.//@data-producturl').extract()
            urls = sel.xpath('.//@data-productimg').extract()

            #prod_url_det = response.urljoin(produrl.extract())
```

Even my scrapy shell doesnt seem to be returning results.

This xpath seems to be returning results:

```
response.xpath('//div[@ng-app="searchApp"]//div[@id="content"]')
```

However, the following ones are not:

```
response.xpath('//div[@ng-app="searchApp"]//div[@id="content"]//div[@ng-switch="resultTemplate"]')

response.xpath('//div[@ng-app="searchApp"]//div[@id="content"]//div[@class="ng-scope"]')
```

It looks pretty straight forward. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: You have a regular `scrapy.Spider` - not the `CrawlSpider` - and you are having these `rules` defined..is this intentional?